# Python insert array elements into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

I am processing images and converting into around 400 data values.  I want each one of these values to be stored in a column. My mysql table has got columns like these:

```
MYID, WIDTH, HEIGHT,P1,P2,P3.....P400.
```

I can easily save these into a csv file, but since the processing happens on around 3 million files I thought I will write these output directly to a mysql table instead of creating multiple csv files.

This is what I have written so far:

```
for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
    filename = imagePath[imagePath.rfind("/") + 1:]
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    rows, cols, channels = image.shape
    if not image is None:
        features = detail.describe(image)
        features = [str(x) for x in features]
        fileparam = [filename,cols,rows]
        sqldata = fileparam+features
        var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(sqldata))
        query_string = 'INSERT INTO lastoneweeknew VALUES (%s)' % var_string
        y.execute(query_string, sqldata)
```

If I print sqldata, it gets printed like this:

```
['120546506.jpg',650, 420, '0.0', '0.010269055',........., '0.8539078']
```

The mysql table has these data types:

```
+----------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| image_id | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| MYID     | int(10)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| WIDTH    | decimal(6,2)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| HEIGHT   | decimal(6,2)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| P1       | decimal(22,20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| P2       | decimal(22,20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

When I insert the data into mysql table I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

However, when I write the output to csv file and insert the csv data into mysql using R, I could insert without any trouble.

I thought the row and column values are integers and the rest looks like text in the output and hence I converted them to text.

```
row = str(rows)
col = str(cols)
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For your error - %s can only be used to format string arguments, but some of your arguments are int types - thus the type error.

It looks like you are trying to build a data frame and upload it to a MySQL database - luckily this is a common task so there is a library called pandas that can do this all for you. If you create a list of dictionaries where each of the dictionarys key-value pairs are ColumnName: Value.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
import MySQLdb

def handlePaths(imagePaths):
    imageDataList = []
    for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
        filename = imagePath[imagePath.rfind("/") + 1:]
        image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
        rows, cols, channels = image.shape
        if not image is None:
            features = detail.describe(image)
            features = [str(x) for x in features]
            fileparam = [filename,cols,rows]
            sqldata = fileparam+features
            imageData = {"MYID" : value,
             "WIDTH" : value,
             "HEIGHT": value,
             "P1": value, #I would do these iterivly 
             .....,
             "P400": value}
            imageDataList.append(imageData)
    imageDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(imageDataList)
    database_connection = MySQLdb.connect()  # may need to add some other options to connect
    imageDataFrame.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='lastoneweeknew', if_exists='replace')
```

I assume this is a pretty cpu-consuming process, you could assign an image to each cpu to make it run quicker, By uploaded each individual entry you let the database handle the race conditions.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
import MySQLdb
import multiprocessing

def analyzeImages(imagePaths) #imagePaths is a list of image paths
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_count)
    pool.map(handleSinglePath, imagePaths)
    pool.join()
    pool.close()

def handleSinglePath(imagePath):
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath) #Not sure what you where doing before here but you can do it again 
    rows, cols, channels = image.shape
    if not image is None:
        features = detail.describe(image)
        features = [str(x) for x in features]
        fileparam = [filename,cols,rows]
        sqldata = fileparam+features
        imageData = {"MYID" : value,
         "WIDTH" : value,
         "HEIGHT": value,
         "P1": value, #I would do these iterivly 
         .....,
         "P400": value}
    imageDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(imageData)
    database_connection = MySQLdb.connect()  # may need to add some other options to connect
    imageDataFrame.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='lastoneweeknew', if_exists='replace')
```